# AES_DECRYPT with MySQL JOIN Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a JOIN query that works perfectly fine without using MySQL encryption. But when I try to decrypt the rows, the query fails.

> Select members.name, member_notes.sin, member_notes.note, member_notes.admin_note, member_notes.username, member_notes.time_stamp from member_notes JOIN members on member_notes.sin = members.sin

I'm querying 2 tables:

1. member_notes
2. members

The SIN field is identical in both.

I am trying to decrypt the name in the above query as follows:

> AES_DECRYPT(members.name, '$key') as members.name

The query fails when I try to decrypt. **Note: I am able to decrypt without joining the two tables.**

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
Select 
    members.name, member_notes.sin, member_notes.note, 
    member_notes.admin_note, member_notes.username, member_notes.time_stamp, 
    CAST(AES_DECRYPT(members.name, '$key') as CHAR) as name 
from member_notes 
JOIN members on member_notes.sin = members.sin
```